# printf in code composer studio for tiva series

Tags: c, arm

I am using Code Composer Studio (CCS) for developing an embedded application. It is very helpful if I can use printf to print something on console of CCS. But it is not working. I included **stdio.h**. The Code compiles. When I run, I see data in putty, but I see nothing in CCS. Is is possible to see something in console like in eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Printf_support_for_MSP430_CCSTUDIO_compiler

contains the details on how to use printf() (per some compiler settings in the CCS) to display the results of printf() statements on the CCS console

in the 'properties' window, in the 'Library Function Assumptions' sub page, in the 'Level of printf() support required' select 'full'